# Serenity/JS - Any Code changes made unable to run

Tags: javascript, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity, serenity-js

I am newbie to JS and typescript. 
Was able to to run the sample project shared in Git Hub, but if any changes made, there are errors.
For Example : Any import statement added or any browser related actions under step_definitions.
Can you please guide how to proceed?
Is there any detailed tutorial available for the same?

I have experience in working with Serenity Framework in Java.

Regards,
Divya

Answer (score 0):

Hello and thanks for giving Serenity/JS a try :-)

The official tutorials are [listed](https://github.com/jan-molak/serenity-js#tutorials) on the [project's Github page](https://github.com/jan-molak/serenity-js).
They describe how to add the required dependencies, import any Serenity/JS-specific classes and interfaces, how to define custom tasks and so on.

If you'd like to have a look at a finished implementation of what you'd end up with having followed the tutorials, you could check out [serenity-js-getting-started](https://github.com/jan-molak/serenity-js-getting-started) project, and specifically the branch called [2-reports](https://github.com/jan-molak/serenity-js-getting-started/tree/2-reports).

Hope that helps!

Jan

Comment: > serenity-js-getting-started@1.0.0 pretest <PROJECT_PATH>
> serenity update

info: Looks like you need the latest Serenity BDD CLI jar. Let me download it for you...
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Comment: Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
    at Error (native)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1060:38)
    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:584:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:416:38)
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.

Comment: Unable to run due to the above error                                                                     versions Used:
node : 6.2.1
npm : 3.10.2
typescript : 2.1.4
serenity-cli : 0.1.4
protractor-cucumber-framework : 0.6.0
serenity-js : 0.7.0

Comment: Do you happen to be behind a corporate proxy that adds self-signed certificates?

Comment: Yes, But this is the first time i am running into this problem. The first time i had imported, the test went to the pending state as expected

Comment: It does look like an issue with your proxy configuration; Check out https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3742#issuecomment-225939382 to see how you can configure node to use self-signed certification. Hope that helps!

Comment: I was able to run the project, but the report in the target folder,(index.html), does not show any report, such as pass, fail or pending status.